# How to achieve nested slivers? A sliver containing a list of slivers

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sliver

`SliverList` is a sliver that contains box widgets. Is there a sliver that contains sliver widgets?

I am attempting to nest flutter_sticky_headers to create a timeline, but `SliverStickyHeader` only accepts a single sliver as an argument (see comment in `monthSlivers()`).

```
class HomeView extends StatelessWidget {
  final HomeViewModel viewModel;

  HomeView(this.viewModel);

  List<Widget> entryTiles(List<EntryTileViewModel> entryVMs) {
    return entryVMs.map((entryVM) => EntryTile(viewModel: entryVM)).toList();
  }

  List<Widget> daySlivers(List<DaySection> daySections) {
    return daySections.map((daySection) {
      var entries = entryTiles(daySection.entryVMs);
      return SliverStickyHeader(
        overlapsContent: true,
        header: DayHeader(
          viewModel: DayHeaderViewModel(date: daySection.date),
        ),
        sliver: SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (context, i) => entries[i],
            childCount: entries.length,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  List<Widget> monthSlivers() {
    return viewModel.monthSections.map((monthSection) {
      var days = daySlivers(monthSection.daySections);
      return SliverStickyHeader(
        header: MonthHeader(
          viewModel: MonthHeaderViewModel(date: monthSection.date),
        ),
        sliver:,// THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO PUT DAYSLIVERS().
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: monthSlivers(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`sliver_tools`](https://pub.dev/packages/sliver_tools#multisliver) package. It has a widget called `MultiSliver` that your desired result could be achieved by this. As documentation mentioned :

> The MultiSliver widget allows for grouping of multiple slivers
> together such that they can be returned as a single widget. For
> instance when one wants to wrap a few slivers with some padding or an
> inherited widget.

and this is an example :

```
class WidgetThatReturnsASliver extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiSliver(
      children: <Widget>[
        SliverPersistentHeader(...),
        SliverList(...),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

or you can use it inside a `CustomScrollView` :

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers:[
    MultiSliver(
      SliverList(...),
      SliverGrid(...),
      ...
    )
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using this right now in my projects

```dart
class SliverSection extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Widget> slivers;

  const SliverSection({Key key, this.slivers}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return  SliverToBoxAdapter(
     child: ShrinkWrappingViewport(
       offset: ViewportOffset.zero(),
       slivers: slivers,
     ),
   );
  }
}
```

I haven't try of it affects performance

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CustomScrollView()` with slivers as named parameter which receives list of slivers or `NestedScrollView()`

Comment: I have growable list (infinite scroll) in `CustomScrollView`. I wrapped the list inside `SliverFillRemaining` with hasScrollBody true and `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics`. This make me cannot scroll to the end of the list, if changed to `ScrollPhysics` it will result in having 2 scroll viewport and allow scrolling to the end of the list. So i tried another way, i wrapped the list inside `SliverList` and give it expanded or without expanded. Anything not work. I expected that's able to scroll to the end of the list without having multiple scroll viewport.

Answer (score 0):

If your slivers are already contained in a CustomScrollView and you actually want to return multiple slivers for a certain case, a solution would be to wrap them in a list and use the spread operator.

> ...[Sliver1(), Sliver2(),]