# How to have a nested SliverList in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-sliver

I am using a SliverAppBar and SliverList inside a CustomScrollView. Now I want to build a another ListView inside the SliverList I have. But it doesn't let me.

Comment: This one answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/68156899/11217945

Answer (score 0):

You will need a `NestedScrollView`

Here's an example:-

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
     appBar: SliverAppBar(),
      body: new NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            new SliverAppBar(
              pinned: true,
              title: new Text('Flutter Demo'),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new FlutterLogo(size: 100.0, colors: Colors.purple),
            new Container(
              height: 300.0,
              child: new ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 60,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return new Text('Item $index');
                },
              ),
            ),
            new FlutterLogo(size: 100.0, colors: Colors.orange),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```